# Forms Recognizer can't identify fields without : as keys

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I've been using Forms Recognizer for some days now and can't get it to recognize the keys in my forms.

I want to use it to extract the answers given by students in a test...[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afUQc.png) is an example.

I can't change the structure of the sheet students fill because it is a national exam and I don't have access to who organizes it.

So I trained a model as recommended on Microsoft documentation and used it to "read" the forms and it gets most of the answers, but it all comes as values of a key "**Tokens**"

```
{
    "key": [
      {
        "text": "__Tokens__",
        "boundingBox": [
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0
        ]
      }
    ],
    "value": [
      {
        "text": "01",
        "boundingBox": [
          110.1,
          826.6,
          125.6,
          826.6,
          125.6,
          816.8,
          110.1,
          816.8
        ],
        "confidence": 1
      },
      {
        "text": "A",
        "boundingBox": [
          148.2,
          834.4,
          160.6,
          834.4,
          160.6,
          816.8,
          148.2,
          816.8
        ],
        "confidence": 1
      },
      {
        "text": "26",
        "boundingBox": [
          229.4,
          828.6,
          246,
          828.6,
          246,
          816.8,
          229.4,
          816.8
        ],
        "confidence": 1
      },
      {
        "text": "B",
        "boundingBox": [
          268.6,
          834.4,
          277.8,
          834.4,
          277.8,
          816.8,
          268.6,
          816.8
        ],
        "confidence": 1
      }
```

Then I recreated the structure on excel but with : after the numbers and trained another model. I also printed some copies of it and filled in to test and Form Recognizer understood the numbers as keys.

```
{
      "key": [
        {
          "text": "01:",
          "boundingBox": [
            270.4,
            1625.4,
            313,
            1625.4,
            313,
            1600.5,
            270.4,
            1600.5
          ]
        }
      ],
      "value": [
        {
          "text": "A",
          "boundingBox": [
            350.7,
            1620.9,
            368.8,
            1620.9,
            368.8,
            1587,
            350.7,
            1587
          ],
          "confidence": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "key": [
        {
          "text": "26:",
          "boundingBox": [
            520.2,
            1624.2,
            552.8,
            1624.2,
            552.8,
            1600.5,
            520.2,
            1600.5
          ]
        }
      ],
      "value": [
        {
          "text": "E",
          "boundingBox": [
            604.6,
            1618.8,
            625.8,
            1618.8,
            625.8,
            1587,
            604.6,
            1587
          ],
          "confidence": 1
        }
      ]
    }
```

Does anyone know some way to recognize the number fields as keys without the : ?

Answer (score 0):

Form Recognizer will not consider the row numbers as keys unless specifically marked as keys, hence it currently does not discover them as keys.

Comment: Hi, Neta...thanks for the information. Do you know if there are any improvements planned for form recognizer and when are they expected to happen?

Comment: See Form Recognizer latest announcement for all the new features https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-cognitive-services-for-building-enterprise-ready-scalable-ai-solutions/

Comment: Thanks!! Any ideia when the labelling features will be available?